# Manhwa where the female lead repeatedly dies and reincarnates again; killed by brother / hated by family

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I once saw this on TikTok a year ago I think.

Something like a female lead died many times (<10 I guess and came back as the same person) trying to get loved/liked by her family, but at the end it's futile and she's exhausted already. So she said to her brother that in her next life, she won't be trying anymore and be forgiving, like this is the last one, and her brother was stunned and shouted at her, but she died again. (They exchanged those while she was in prison?) Her family doesn't like her or abused her. I think she got abused to death or poison? I forgot actually.

Please, if any of you remember?

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: No, I don't.  My apologies.

Comment: Was she definitely in a prison/jail for one scene? There's at least two manhwa I can think of with this premise, just off the top of my head. I don't recall either having a prison/jail scene though.

Comment: The prison/jail was just a guess . But the main points I remembered were she was hated and she died everytime up to 7th times. And on the 7th life before she died, she said like gist of something it's the last one like she won't try again anymore to make efforts to be loved/liked by the family anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ***[Can We Become Family?](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/can-we-become-family)***...?

> Adopted from a poor, rural orphanage by a wealthy duke, Naviah Agnus wanted nothing but to win her new father’s heart. Despite her best efforts, the calculating Duke only sees Naviah as a pawn, a mere stand-in for his terminally ill daughter Vivian, who was set to marry the crown prince. But when Vivian miraculously recovers, Naviah is pushed aside and driven to her own death. When she wakes up, she is 8 years old again, but this time, Naviah is done playing nice. Can they ever really become family?
>
> [image: Promotional art for "Can We Become Family?."]

As noted in the plot summary above, the protagonist, Naviah Agnus, was adopted by a duke as a stand-in for his sick daughter, Vivian. Naviah worked hard to win her father's love and truly be accepted as part of the family, but her father turns against her when it's discovered that some tea she brought to Vivian was poisoned.

When she and her brother, Eudes, are alone, she tells him she knows it was he who poisoned Vivian's tea, and he confesses that he's always hated Naviah, believing that commoners shouldn't be allowed into noble society. He tosses her a vial of poison, which she willingly drinks. Before dying, she explains to him that this is the seventh time she's gone back in time and relived the same life, but she only has one life left, and she won't waste it trying to be a part of the Agnus family like she did before. Angered by her remarks, he begins to reply, but it's too late; she's already dead. She then wakes up in bed as her eight-year-old self again.

You can read the full manhwa at [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/can-we-become-family/info).

Comment: I checked the panels out. It coincides what I saw. Thank you so much! This is it